# Degree of a map given by a rational function.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a complete nonsingular curve and $f \in K(X)$ a rational function. By the general theory there is the map $g: X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ which usually people write as $x \to (f(x) :1)$.
I have two questions. The first one is: how to recover the degree of $g$ from it?

As far as I understand the strategy is the following: take $k(f)$ the minimal subfield of $K(X)$ which contains $f$, then $k(f)$ is of transcendence degree $1$ over $k$. Thus, $[K(X): k(f)]$ is finite and it is out desired degree.

If my suggestion is correct, then note that then we can construct, for example, degree $2$ ramified covers of $\mathbb{P}^1$ by taking $k(x)[y]/(y^2-q)$ where $q \in k(x)$. And in general for a field $K$ of transcendence degree $1$ over $k$ we can consider $K[\sqrt[n]{w}$] for $w \in K$. The second question is: how to understand the corresponding curve? For example, how to find its genus? I think we can use the Riemann-Hurwitz theorem but then we need to understand the ramification locus which I don't see how to do.

Comment: If you search for "cyclic covers of the projective line" or "superelliptic curves", you may find what you're looking for. For instance, Neurohr's thesis may have it: http://oops.uni-oldenburg.de/3607/1/neueff18.pdf

Answer (score 1):

By facts in the question, $w \in K$ gives you a map $f_w \colon X \to \mathbb{P}^1$.
Then the branched cover of $X$ corresponding to $K[\sqrt[n]{w}]$ is the pullback along $f_w$ of the $n$-sheeted branched cover $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$ given by $[s:t] \mapsto [s^n : t^n]$.